# Search for word and add additional word to it and together copy to new row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need small help. My problem is:

In sheet A under column A and B I have following:

```
       Column A       |     Column B
----------------------|-------------------
 New Orleans, Buffalo |  Miami, Atlanta 
        etc           |       etc
         .            |        .
         .            |        .
```

I need formula to compare this words with `Column C` full names

```
    Column C
New Orleans Saints
Miami Doplhins 
       etc
        .
        .
```

And Paste them to lets say Sheet 2 under column A and B as full name

```
       Column A     |    Column B
--------------------|-------------------
 New Orleans Saints |  Miami Dolphins
         etc        |       etc
          .         |        .
          .         |        .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is consistent i.e. `Column A` and `Column B` are in format `xxx, yyy` and you want to search for `xxx` in `Column C`, then as per image below enter the following formula in `Cell E2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$50,MATCH(LEFT(A2,(FIND(",",A2,1)-1))&"*",$C$2:$C$50,0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy this formula to `Column F` and down as required. Change range as per your data.

[image]

Or if you want result in `Sheet2` then enter following formula in `Cell A2` of `Sheet2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10,MATCH(LEFT(Sheet1!A2,(FIND(",",Sheet1!A2,1)-1))&"*",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$50,0)),"")
```

Drag/Copy this formula in `Cell B2` and down as required. Change range as per your data.

Comment: This is working and I managed to combine everything except same names. If I have 2 teams from same city gives me first one.